# Accessing ServletContext in any class

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons

I am trying to access property file from `webapps/WEB-INF/` folder which is implemented in a util class.
 Util class don't have `ServletContext`. Plus property file be used by test cases when server is stopped.
How can I access `ServletContext` in any java class?

Comment: How are you accessing it now?

Comment: Earlier I was accessing through absolute path given by `-Dlocation` value.

Comment: Give it a servlet context. Or put it on the classpath and access it as a resource. Or provide an absolute location via a `-D` parameter or other configuration value.